# How to use custom global declaration in NextJS 14

Tags: typescript, next.js, .d.ts

I want to use custom global declaration in NextJS

I have a NextJS project in which I have created a global prototype to String like below

utils.d.ts

```
export {}

declare global {
  interface String {
    /**
     * Returns string after removing all html tags.
     */
    stripHtml(): string
  }
}
String.prototype.stripHtml = function (): string {
  return this.replace(/(<([^>]+)>)/gi, '')
}
```

Then I've included utils.d.ts file in tsconfig.json like below

tsconfig.json

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "es5",
    "lib": ["dom", "dom.iterable", "esnext"],
    "allowJs": true,
    "skipLibCheck": true,
    "strict": true,
    "forceConsistentCasingInFileNames": true,
    "noEmit": true,
    "esModuleInterop": true,
    "module": "esnext",
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "resolveJsonModule": true,
    "isolatedModules": true,
    "jsx": "preserve",
    "incremental": true,
    "paths": {
      "@/*": ["./*"]
    },
    "experimentalDecorators": true,
    "emitDecoratorMetadata": true
  },
  "include": ["utils.d.ts", "next-env.d.ts", "**/*.ts", "**/*.tsx"],
  "exclude": ["node_modules"]
}
```

Then I've used it inside my component Example.tsx like below

Exmaple.tsx

```
import React from 'react'

interface Props {
  posts: Record<string, any>[]
}

const Example: React.FC<Props> = ({ posts }) => {
  return (
    <section>
      <div className="container">
        <div>
          {posts.map((item, idx) => {
            const post = item.attributes
            const { title, content } = post
            return (
              <div key={`post-${idx}`}>
                <div>
                  <h2>{title}</h2>
                  <p>{content.stripHtml()}</p>
                </div>
              </div>
            )
          })}
        </div>
      </div>
    </section>
  )
}

export default Example
```

Now VS Code is recognizing the declaration and not showing any red lines like before. Now when I'm running the project using dev command getting below error.

```
TypeError: content.stripHtml is not a function
    at eval (webpack-internal:///./components/Example.tsx:37:58)
    at Array.map (<anonymous>)
    at Example (webpack-internal:///./components/Example.tsx:21:40)
    at renderWithHooks (/Users/vickyvish/Projects/eweb-next/node_modules/react-dom/cjs/react-dom-server.browser.development.js:5658:16)
    at renderIndeterminateComponent (/Users/vickyvish/Projects/eweb-next/node_modules/react-dom/cjs/react-dom-server.browser.development.js:5731:15)
    at renderElement (/Users/vickyvish/Projects/eweb-next/node_modules/react-dom/cjs/react-dom-server.browser.development.js:5946:7)
    at renderNodeDestructiveImpl (/Users/vickyvish/Projects/eweb-next/node_modules/react-dom/cjs/react-dom-server.browser.development.js:6104:11)
    at renderNodeDestructive (/Users/vickyvish/Projects/eweb-next/node_modules/react-dom/cjs/react-dom-server.browser.development.js:6076:14)
    at renderNode (/Users/vickyvish/Projects/eweb-next/node_modules/react-dom/cjs/react-dom-server.browser.development.js:6259:12)
    at renderChildrenArray (/Users/vickyvish/Projects/eweb-next/node_modules/react-dom/cjs/react-dom-server.browser.development.js:6211:7)
    at renderNodeDestructiveImpl (/Users/vickyvish/Projects/eweb-next/node_modules/react-dom/cjs/react-dom-server.browser.development.js:6141:7)
    at renderNodeDestructive (/Users/vickyvish/Projects/eweb-next/node_modules/react-dom/cjs/react-dom-server.browser.development.js:6076:14)
    at renderNode (/Users/vickyvish/Projects/eweb-next/node_modules/react-dom/cjs/react-dom-server.browser.development.js:6259:12)
    at renderChildrenArray (/Users/vickyvish/Projects/eweb-next/node_modules/react-dom/cjs/react-dom-server.browser.development.js:6211:7)
    at renderNodeDestructiveImpl (/Users/vickyvish/Projects/eweb-next/node_modules/react-dom/cjs/react-dom-server.browser.development.js:6141:7)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You did everything correct in sense of TypeScript, however the problem was that you did not extend the String prototype with the function stripHtml, hence the error: "stripHtml is not a function.".

The correct solution would be to declare the type in a `utils.d.ts` file and extend String prototype in a separate file `utils.ts`, then import it once at the top-level of the app.

The app's root `layout.tsx` would be the most optimal place to import it, that way it is accessible in the whole the components tree.

*Example:*

**File: utils.ts**

```
import './utils.d'

String.prototype.stripHtml = function (): string {
    return this.replace(/(<([^>]+)>)/gi, '')
}
```

**File: utils.d.ts**

```
export {}

declare global {
    interface String {
        /**
         * Returns string after removing all html tags.
         */
        stripHtml(): string
    }
}
```

**File: app/layout.tsx**

```
import '@/utils'
```

Edit: P.s. This practice is usually called prototype pollution which is a bad practice, for reasons that I won't ramble on here as there are many articles explaining the reasoning of it. One suggestion would be to declare the util function in a module and import it only in files where it's needed.

Answer (score 0):

maybe this can help:

1. Ensure `tsconfig.json` is being used by the ts compiler.
2. After the build, check the js files to ensure that `stripHtml` exists in the `String.prototype`
3. The import order, make sure that `utils.d.ts` file is being imported before any other file that uses custom declarations.
4. the most basic, but the one that i always forgot doing: have you restarted the nextjs development server?

if the problem persist, could you share the webpack/ babel configs?

Comment: I am using a framework called NextJS. No webpack or babel config present in the project structure. I only have a tsconfig.json which I have already shared.

Answer (score 0):

Just make sure that `utils.d.ts` included in the build output and imported before using `stripHtml` in your component.

**You can also consider alternative approaches:**

**Utility Function:** If global modification isn't essential, create a utility function instead of extending `String.prototype`:

```
function stripHtml(str: string): string {
  return str.replace(/(<([^>]+)>)/gi, '');
}
```

**Custom Hook:** For reusable logic, create a custom hook:

```
import { useEffect } from 'react';

function useStripHtml() {
  useEffect(() => {
    String.prototype.stripHtml = function () {
      return this.replace(/(<([^>]+)>)/gi, '');
    };
  }, []);
}
```